# Align numeric indexes to temporal period in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a data frame like this:

`0     0.131567 
 1     0.098878 
 2     0.102000
 . ...
 94574 0.088912 
 94575 0.089399`

and I know it corresponds to some time interval eg. 15:57:32 - 16:50:05. So I would like to convert indexes from sequence of number to sequence of timestamps. 
So that output will look like this

```
 15:57:32.000000   0.131567  
 15:57:32.031000   0.102000  
             ...   ...
 16:50:04.969000   0.088912
 16:50:04.000000   0.089399`
```

Perhaps I can do it  with the following code:

```
>     rng = date_range('15:57:32.000000','16:50:04.000000' , freq=??) 
>     ts = Series(data, index=rng)
```

But how should I choose frequency then?
Are there any other way to do it or I am on the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify a multiplier in the freq field. `help(pd.date_range)` gives :

> freq : string or DateOffset, default 'D' (calendar daily)
>       Frequency strings can have multiples, e.g. '5H'

```
rng = pd.date_range('15:57:32','16:50:04',freq='33328us')
```

Then `len(rng)` is exactly `94576` :

```
2016-03-15 15:57:32         0.881135
2016-03-15 15:57:32.033328  0.237618
2016-03-15 15:57:32.066656  0.761269
....
2016-03-15 16:50:03.962272  0.820865
2016-03-15 16:50:03.995600  0.181762
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: BTW how do you come up with this multiplier? It should be 1/30S, right? Where can I find info about multipliers for freq?

Comment: pd.Timedelta('00:52:32')/94575 is Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.033328')